# Clustering Openfire 3.7.1

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am trying for clustering openfire 3.7.1, but still not succeed and don't know what the problem is. Here are the steps:

- First, I install Clustering Plugin 1.2.0 from Plugins menu.
- Then I go to *Server -> Server Manager -> Clustering* menu and got *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tangosol/net/Invocable* exception. Searching on the forum, I found that Clustering Plugin needs Oracle Coherence. So I download Oracle Coherence v3.4.2 and copy all jar files from lib dir into openfire lib dir. Then I restart openfire and now clustering menu seems ok, no exception occurred.
- I try to enable clustering from clustering menu. It states that enabling clustering may take 30 seconds. But after clicking the *Save settings* button, the process won't stop even after 10 minutes. So I stopped the process and restart openfire.
- I login again and everything seems good. Accessing again the Clustering menu, it shows that the clustering is enabled and there is 1 node listed and running. But when I click the nodes link, it does nothing. Also when I try to access 'Users/Group' menu, it shows HTTP ERROR 500 with *org.jivesoftware.util.cache.DefaultCache cannot be cast to com.jivesoftware.util.cache.ClusteredCache* exception.

My machine specs are:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Openfire 3.7.1
- Core i5 with 8 GB memory.

Comment: You know you need a license for coherence right?  I would recommend trying the new approach with Hazelcast instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems be a problem with 1.2.0 Plugin
Look at this post for further help:
http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/218486#218486

Comment: Thank you roman. Yeah the problem is with 1.2.0 plugin itself.